# Why doesn't loss decrease with each epoch (for IMDB data vs Rotten Tomatoes data)

Tags: cnn, text-classification, colab

I am following the [Google tutorial on ML for text classification](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-1)

I made [this Google Colab notebook](https://gist.github.com/theredpea/52d7ab108339636a467f2feb063338bc) which you should be able to run from start to finish to see the issue.

- When the code trains a sequential CNN on IMDB data, the loss doesn't decrease and training stops (due to EarlyStopping).
- When the same code trains a sequential CNN on Rotten Tomato data, the loss decreases (as expected)

At first I could not understand why the IMDB loss failed to decrease, was it the data, the model, something else?

Then I tried Rotten Tomato data and found loss did decrease.

This suggests the data is the problem. *I will try to answer my own question by checking the difference in IMDB data (`load_imdb_sentiment_analysis_dataset(...)`) vs Rotten Tomato data (`load_rotten_tomatoes_sentiment_analysis_dataset(...)`).*

[image: a screenshot of this Google Colab notebook, showing a CNN where loss does not decrease for IMDB data, but a CNN where loss does decrease for Rotten Tomatoes data https://gist.github.com/theredpea/52d7ab108339636a467f2feb063338bc]

**EDIT**

I notice the Rotten Tomatoes data labels have 5 distinct values, creating a multiclass problem

```
 np.unique(rt_labels)
 >> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Whereas the IMDB dataset have only 2 labels; a binary classification problem

```
 np.unique(imdb_labels)
 >> array([0, 1])
```

When I re-train the model on the Rotten Tomatoes dataset, **limited** to just two labels (`class=0`, or `class==4`), then I get the same results (where the loss doesn't decrease from epoch to epoch)... So it's not specific to the data, it's specific to the type of classification problem...

```
train_li = np.isin(rt_data[0][1], (0,4))
test_li = np.isin(rt_data[1][1], (0,4))
rt_result = None
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  rt_result = train_sequence_model(  
    (
        (np.array(rt_data[0][0])[train_li], np.where(rt_data[0][1][train_li]==0, 0,1)),
        (np.array(rt_data[1][0])[test_li], np.where(rt_data[1][1][test_li]==0, 0, 1))
    ), epochs=10)
     # ... outputs where the losses don't decrease ...
```

In general, ML is different in binary classification (`num_classes=2`) vs multiclass classification problems (`num_classes>2`). Specifically this notebook behaves differently in at least 3 ways:

First, in choosing the loss function:

```
if num_classes == 2:
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
else:
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```

Second, in choosing the activation function and third, choosing the number of output units for the neural network:

```
if num_classes == 2:
    activation = 'sigmoid'
    units = 1
else:
    activation = 'softmax'
    units = num_classes
```

So I think these have something to do with my answer... more later...